# extracting details from text and writing them in separate files

Tags: python, regex

The following is an example.txt, which contains the statistics of many queues.
My aim is to extract the details of individual queues (from example.txt) and put them in separate log files (queue_0.log, queue_1.log .. etc).

```
some details:

sn  size    fbe     lbe     fbl     lbl     latency
log_rx_packets_start_queue 0
0   512     1.6     3.2     3.2     4.8     1.6
1   512     3.2     4.8     4.8     6.4     1.6
.
.
97  512     156.8   158.4   158.4   160     1.59999999999999
98  512     158.4   160     160     161.6   1.59999999999999
99  512     160     161.6   161.6   163.2   1.59999999999999
log_rx_packets_end_queue 0

************************************
--- Received Packet Statistics --- For Queue 0
***********************************

Number of packets sent : 100
Number of packets received : 100


log_rx_packets_start_queue 1
0   512     161.6   163.2   163.2   164.8   1.59999999999999
1   512     163.2   164.8   164.8   166.4   1.59999999999999
2   512     164.8   166.4   166.4   168     1.59999999999999
.
.
98  512     318.4   320     320     321.6   1.60000000000002
99  512     320     321.6   321.6   323.2   1.60000000000002
log_rx_packets_end_queue 1

************************************
--- Received Packet Statistics --- For Queue 1
***********************************

Number of packets sent : 100
Number of packets received : 100


log_rx_packets_start_queue 2
0   512     321.6   323.2   323.2   324.8   1.60000000000002
1   512     323.2   324.8   324.8   326.4   1.60000000000002
.
.
99  512     480.000000000003        481.600000000003        481.600000000003        483.200000000003        1.60000000000002
log_rx_packets_end_queue 2

************************************
--- Received Packet Statistics --- For Queue 2
***********************************

Number of packets sent : 100
Number of packets received : 100

...
...
// Similarly continues
```

For now I have been successful in getting the log of only one queue(queue_0.log). Could anyone give some idea on how I can extend this and get the log for all the queues and also put them in separate directory.

```
import os
import re

newpath = 'results'
if not os.path.exists(newpath):
    os.makedirs(newpath) # need to check exception here


#input_file = open("log.txt", "r")
qno_start = 0
qno_end = 0
grab_lines = False
filename='output'

with open('example.txt','r') as ip_file:
   print "Reading"
   data = []
   for line in ip_file:
       match_qno_start = re.match(r'\s*log_rx_packets_start_queue ([0_9])', line)
       match_qno_end = re.match(r'\s*log_rx_packets_end_queue ([0_9])', line)

       if match_qno_start:
           qno_start = match_qno_start.group(0)
           grab_lines = True
           output_name='queue_'+match_qno_start.group(1)+'.log'
           output_file = open(output_name, "w")
           continue


       elif match_qno_end:  
           qno_end = match_qno_end.group(0)
           grab_lines = False

       if grab_lines:
           new_line = data.append(line);

for i in data:
    output_file.write(i)
```

Comment: `[0_9]` only matches `0`, `_` and `9`. You need `[0-9]`, or alternatively `\d`.

Comment: And using a generator can simply your code a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done using a regular expression as follows:

```
import re

with open('example.txt') as f_input:
    data = f_input.read()

    for match in re.finditer(r'log_rx_packets_start_queue (\d+)\n(.*?)log_rx_packets_end_queue', data, re.M + re.S):
        queue, block =  match.groups()

        with open('queue_{}.log'.format(queue), 'w') as f_output:
            f_output.write(block)
```

For each block, it creates a log file based on the queue name. It does assume that your data file fits into memory. So for example your first output log file would appear as:

```
0   512     1.6     3.2     3.2     4.8     1.6
1   512     3.2     4.8     4.8     6.4     1.6
97  512     156.8   158.4   158.4   160     1.59999999999999
98  512     158.4   160     160     161.6   1.59999999999999
99  512     160     161.6   161.6   163.2   1.59999999999999
```